# snowflake drivers for sql server

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

as a newbie to snowflake, with a potential project  for snowflake/sql server integration (for SSAS), I'd like to know whether there are some mature ODBC or OLE drivers for ingesting data from Snowflake into SSAS, or whether dumping data to text files is the only high-speed/volume data mechanism to import to SSAS, particularly for older version, such as SSAS 2014 (while considering upgrade paths).

thank you kindly,
Cos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are odbc drivers but odbc is not a good solution (for any source/target) for high volume data movement. Whether it would be a workable solution for you is dependent on your data volumes, required performance, etc.